# What role did Matt Damon play in Thor: Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

Going through filmography of Matt Damon, I found that he acted in *Thor: Ragnarok*.

[image: Matt Damon in Thor Ragnarok]

When I couldn't recall him from my memory of *Thor: Ragnarok*, I googled. But, his role is nowhere to be found.

[image: Thor Ragnarok casts with Matt Damon]

What role did Matt Damon play in *Thor: Ragnarok*?

Comment: He's [credited in IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/characters/nm0000354?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t62) as playing an actor playing Loki in the play-within-a-movie.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just after Thor returns to Asgard, he stumbles upon a play being performed to "Odin" (disguised Loki).  The actor playing the [actor portraying Loki](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/characters/nm0000354?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t62) is Matt Damon.

[image: Matt Damon as Loki]

Comment: Wow! They picked Matt Damon for such small role.

Comment: @TimeLord - https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/matt-damon-explains-why-thor-ragnarok-cameo/ - he's friends w/ Chris and Taika and thought it would be funny - it wasn't a 'real' casting decision

Comment: Loki plays Loki ))

Comment: @TimeLord both he has a alot of mall cameos like the singer in the Movie Euro-trip or a random redneck in Deadpool 2.